# Is LINQ breadth-first or depth-first?

Tags: .net, linq, sql-execution-plan

Does LINQ execute breadth-first or depth-first?

For example, consider the following snippet:

```
var stories = syndicationFeed.Items
  .Select ( item => ConstructStory ( item ) )
  .Where ( story => story != null )
  .OrderByDescending ( story => story.WhenPublished )
  .ToList();
```

Is the select clause executed in it entirety before the where clause is applied (as likewise for the order clause)? Or is the first object in the final list computed before attempting to compute the next object?

Comment: It depends, are you using LinqToObjects (Working with `IEnumerable`s) or LinqToEntites (Working with `IQueryable`s)

Comment: I'm specifically referring to LinqToObjects (with IEnumerable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is the select clause executed in it entirety before the where clause is applied"

If you are working with LinqToEntites (`IQueyable` objects) it is up to the Driver that talks to the data source to determine the order.

If you are working with LinqToObjects it pipelines the process where it can, so it does ***not*** perform the `Select` on every object before the first one has its filter checked, the filter is checked ***during*** the select evaluation. Your code is roughly equivalent to.

```
List<Story> YourCode(Feed syndicationFeed)
{
    IEnumerable<Story> storiesAsIEnumrable = syndicationFeed.EquivlantFunctionUpToToList()
    var stories = storiesAsIEnumrable.ToList(storiesAsIEnumrable);

    return stories;
}

IEnumerable<Story> EquivlantFunctionUpToToList(Feed feed)
{
    List<Story> storyBufferForSorting = new List<Story>();
    foreach(item in feed.Items)
    {
        var story = ConstructStory(item);
        if(story != null)
        {
            storyBufferForSorting.Add(story);
        }
    }
    storyBufferForSorting.OrderBy((x,y) => y.WhenPublished.CompareTo(x.WhenPublushed));
    return storyBufferForSorting;
}

//Taken right from the .NET framework source code via ILSpy
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

So yes, the items get fully enumerated before the sort (it must so it can figure out which item is "first"), and a full enumeration happens again to create the list in the `ToList()`, but the filter happens during the first enumeration process, not as a extra pass.

Answer (score 0):

If `syndicationFeed.Items` is an `IQueryable`, the query will be built by combining the various methods until the data is actually requested (in this case by the call to `ToList()`).

However, this really depends on what kind of data you're querying and what operations you want performed against it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no definite answer for that (assuming you talk about "Linq to Entities"). I believe that this depends on the "Linq to Entities" driver which translates the "Linq to Entities" query in an SQL query. Then it depends on the way the SQL Server (or any other database server) handles the specific query.

If you really care about performance that much, I would suggest to profile the specific query. Using SQL server you have the ability to see the execution plan. Perhaps this will answer your question. Check [SQL server profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) and [SQL Server execution planning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx).

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

You said you are referring to LinqToObjects (using the extension methods on Enumarble(of T)).

Most LinqToObjects methods are using the yield keyword in the implementation and Select is one of those.
It means that it **doesn't** "select" all the items and then proceeds to the next action, it does it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Linq (to objects) methods can be **streaming** or **non-streaming**. There's a complete overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882641.aspx).

Most of this can be understood by common sense. A `Select` can stream its data to a subsequent LINQ method, because it can "fire and forget" individual items. `OrderBy`, on the other hand, obviously needs to know all elements before it can do anything. So `Select` is streaming, `OrderBy` is not. Likewise, `Where` is streaming because, again, it only needs to deal with one element at a time.

You can check this by putting trace statements into the delegates that serve as arguments of LINQ methods. I did a simple test with some objects I happened to have somewhere. In Linqpad:

```
Crops.Select (c => { ("s-" + c.CrpId).Dump(); return c.CrpId;})
    .Where(i => { ("w1-" + i).Dump(); return i > 120; })
    .Where(i => { ("w2-" + i).Dump(); return i > 150; })
    .OrderBy (i => { ("o-" + i).Dump(); return i; })
```

As you see, the lambda expression are replaced by method bodies, which essentially doesn't make any difference. The output was:

```
s-21
w1-21
s-93
w1-93
...
s-122
w1-122
w2-122
s-123
w1-123
w2-123
...
s-158
w1-158
w2-158
o-155
o-157
o-158
```

So you see that the `Where` and the `Select`s are streamed, and the `OrderBy` waits until all items are available. This also causes the second `Select` (which is a bit contrived here, OK) to execute only when necessary.